# LEAFLET Show spin while map is rendered

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to show a spin while waiting that a layer is rendered on the map, but for some reason, the spinner is not working.

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Spin/leaflet.spin.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Spin/spin.js/dist/spin.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="showMap('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')">TF.Landscape</a>&nbsp;|<a href="#" onclick="showMap('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')">TF.Outdoors</a>
<div id="map" style="width: 640px; height: 480px"></div>

<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"> </script>
<script>
    var map;
    var tileLayer;
    function showMap (layerURL) {
        if(!map) { 
          map = L.map('map').setView([19.5, -73], 7); 
        }

        tileLayer = L.tileLayer(layerURL, {
              attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
              maxZoom: 18
        });

        map.spin(true);
            setTimeout(function () {
                map.addLayer(tileLayer);    
                map.spin(false);
           }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: By "not working" you mean what?

Comment: it is not showing the spinning image while the map is loading

Answer (score 0):

Load the spin-library after loading the leaflet.js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />

<a href="#" onclick="showMap('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')">TF.Landscape</a>&nbsp;|<a href="#" onclick="showMap('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')">TF.Outdoors</a>
<div id="map" style="width: 640px; height: 480px"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"> </script
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Spin/leaflet.spin.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Spin/spin.js/dist/spin.min.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: now show the spinning image, but it does not dissapear when the map finishes its loading.

Comment: Tried this in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwdg6ux3/) - works fine for me, spin shows while loading and disappears when map is shown.

Comment: How would I use this with R Shiny?